# How to call another task with argument in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I want to call another task with argument like this:

```
FILES = `find . -type d -name '*_server' -maxdepth 1`
UNAME = $(shell uname)

build:
ifeq (${UNAME}, Darwin)
build: build-os os=darwin # I want to set os to darwin, then call build-os
else
build: build-os os=linux
endif

build-os:
    gox -verbose \
    -os="${os}" \
    -arch="amd64" \
    -output="${DIST}/{{.OS}}-{{.Arch}}/{{.Dir}}" ${FILES}
```

As you can see, task `build` I want to call `build-os` depends on `shell uname`

Comment: `os=darwin make build-os`  : runs `make` command with target `build-os` in an environment where the `os` variable is set to `darwin`

Comment: @MichelBillaud my script have tried you method, it is not ok

Comment: your script, as I see it, tries something really different, that is using os=something in the dependencies of a rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you set the OS and then you use it in the target :

```
FILES = `find . -type d -name '*_server' -maxdepth 1`
UNAME = $(shell uname)

ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
os=darwin
else
os=linux
endif

build: build-os

build-os:
    gox -verbose \
    -os="${os}" \
    -arch="amd64" \
    -output="${DIST}/{{.OS}}-{{.Arch}}/{{.Dir}}" ${FILES}
```

Please be aware that it is recommended that your target name does match the real output of the build. If it's not the case, it's better to use .PHONY targets, like this :

```
.PHONY: build build-output
```